# Using mremap to remap pages into an existing range using MREMAP_FIXED causes error "Bad address"

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

Background: I am developing a data structure which provides a contiguous address range using `mmap`. The first N bytes (rounded up to pagesize, less then physical memory) reside in memory, the remainder is backed by a memory mapped file. To grow the address range the following steps are performed:

- Unmap the file
- Remap the first N bytes into a memory range of final size
- Grow the file
- Map the file into new range after N bytes

To remap the the memory range `mremap`is used

```
void* remap_impl1(std::size_t newcapacity){
    void* newptr = mremap(rawtotaldata, memoryCapacity, newcapacity, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
    return newptr;
}
```

This all works well, until newcapacity exceeds the physical memory size which causes out of memory error. (even though the actual number of pages which are backed by memory should not change). I figured that this is an issue with overcommiting virtual memory.
It can be avoided by allowing overcommitment via `sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory"`

---

Now, I would like to get the code to work in this scenario even if `overcommit_memory` is set to 0.
My idea was to create the new memory range up front using standard `mmap` specifying the flag `MAP_NORESERVE`. According to the man page `proc`:

`/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory: In mode 0, calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not checked`

Afterwards, remap the N bytes into this new memory range using a fixed address.

This is where I need help. Repeatedly growing the address range in this manner causes the error "Bad address" on remapping which I cannot explain.

The following code reproduces the error. It is compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g mmapbug.cpp -o mmapbug`

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>

struct MMapBuffer{
public:
    void* rawtotaldata = nullptr;
    std::size_t memoryCapacity = 0;

    void* get(){
        return rawtotaldata;
    }

    void reserve(std::size_t newcapacity){
        //round up to page boundary
        const std::size_t numpages = (newcapacity + getpagesize() - 1) / getpagesize();
        newcapacity = numpages * getpagesize();

        if(newcapacity > memoryCapacity){
            void* newptr = remap(newcapacity);

            assert(newptr != MAP_FAILED);
            rawtotaldata = newptr;
            memoryCapacity = newcapacity;

            std::cerr << "rawtotaldata is now " << rawtotaldata << "\n";
            std::cerr << "memoryCapacity is now " << memoryCapacity << "\n";
        }
    }

private:
    void* remap_impl1(std::size_t newcapacity){
        void* newptr = mremap(rawtotaldata, memoryCapacity, newcapacity, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
        return newptr;
    }

    void* remap_impl2(std::size_t newcapacity){
        void* newptr = mmap(0, newcapacity, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);
        std::cerr << "remap_impl2 mmap returned " << newptr << "\n";

        if(newptr != MAP_FAILED){
            std::cerr << "remap_impl2 mremap(" << rawtotaldata << ", " << memoryCapacity << ", " 
                << memoryCapacity << ", MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, " << newptr << ")\n";
            void* remapped = mremap(rawtotaldata, memoryCapacity, memoryCapacity, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, newptr);
            if(remapped == MAP_FAILED){
                perror("remap mremap");
                int ret = munmap(newptr, newcapacity);
                if(ret != 0){
                    perror("remap munmap");
                }
                newptr = MAP_FAILED;
            }else{
                assert(remapped == newptr);
            }
        }else{
            perror("remap mmap");
        }

        return newptr;
    }

    void* remap(std::size_t newcapacity){
        void* newptr = nullptr;

        if(rawtotaldata != nullptr){           
            //newptr = remap_impl1(newcapacity);
            newptr = remap_impl2(newcapacity);
        }else{
            //make a fresh range
            newptr = mmap(0, newcapacity, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);
            if(newptr == MAP_FAILED){
                perror("remap mmap fresh");
            }
        }

        return newptr;
    }  
};

int main(){
    MMapBuffer buffer;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        std::cerr << "i = " << i << "\n";
        buffer.reserve(4095 * i);
        //commit memory
        std::memset(buffer.get(), 1, 4095 * i);
    }
}
```

This program produces the following output.

```
i = 1
rawtotaldata is now 0x7f72b471a000
memoryCapacity is now 4096
i = 2
remap_impl2 mmap returned 0x7f72b4718000
remap_impl2 mremap(0x7f72b471a000, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0x7f72b4718000)
rawtotaldata is now 0x7f72b4718000
memoryCapacity is now 8192
i = 3
remap_impl2 mmap returned 0x7f72b4715000
remap_impl2 mremap(0x7f72b4718000, 8192, 8192, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0x7f72b4715000)
remap mremap: Bad address
mmapbug: mmapbug.cpp:32: void MMapBuffer::reserve(std::size_t): Assertion `newptr != MAP_FAILED' failed.
Aborted
```

In the first iteration, the buffer is initialized with ordinary mmap. The second iteration uses the described method of remapping into an existing, larger range.
In the 3rd iteration, which would be the second time doing the remapping, the method fails.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: It might be helpful to dump the contents of `/proc/self/maps` at several points during the program to check that the mappings are actually set up the way you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion by Nate Eldredge I inspected the contents of `/proc/self/maps` and found unexpected issues.

Following shows the program output with dumps of maps. I removed irrelevant map entries for brevity and added some comments

```
i = 1
rawtotaldata is now 0x7f8508816000
memoryCapacity is now 4096
maps dump after memset
7f8508816000-7f8508817000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [rawtotaldata]

i = 2
remap_impl2 mmap 8192 returned 0x7f8508814000
maps dump after remap_impl2 mmap
7f8508814000-7f8508817000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 8192 + 4096 bytes [newptr + rawtotaldata]

remap_impl2 mremap(0x7f8508816000, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0x7f8508814000)
maps dump after remap_impl2 mremap
7f8508814000-7f8508815000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [half of newptr]
7f8508815000-7f8508816000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [half of newptr]


rawtotaldata is now 0x7f8508814000
memoryCapacity is now 8192

i = 3
remap_impl2 mmap 12288 returned 0x7f8508811000
maps dump after remap_impl2 mmap
7f8508811000-7f8508814000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 12288 bytes [newptr]
7f8508814000-7f8508815000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [half of rawtotaldata]
7f8508815000-7f8508816000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [half of rawtotaldata], 8192 bytes contiguous

remap_impl2 mremap(0x7f8508814000, 8192, 8192, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0x7f8508811000)
maps dump after remap_impl2 mremap
7f85087e5000-7f85087eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8508813000-7f8508814000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes, the preceeding 8k are lost?
7f8508814000-7f8508815000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [half of rawtotaldata]
7f8508815000-7f8508816000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 <-- 4096 bytes [half of rawtotaldata],

remap mremap: Bad address
mmapbug2: mmapbug2.cpp:37: void MMapBuffer::reserve(std::size_t): Assertion `newptr != MAP_FAILED' failed.
Aborted
```

For `i = 2` mremap succeeds, but unexpectedly splits the new mapping into two separate mappings while preserving a contiguous address range.
I think this is the root cause for the error when `i = 3`. It seems that mremap cannot perform the remap of a contiguous memory region which spans across multiple mappings. Not only that, but the destination mapping is modified even though the call fails.

---

The solution to the original problem which I wanted to solve, that is, growing a memory mapping beyond the available physical memory size, is simple. It was just an oversight by myself. I did not test this until now because I was focused on above wrong approach.

**When the original mapping with `mmap` is created with the flag `MAP_NORESERVE` `mremap` can overcommit virtual memory.**

I tested this with the following code.

```
int main(){
    //assume there is 20GB of free RAM, but not 40GB.
    std::size_t fitsInMemSize = 20ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull;
    std::size_t exceedsMemSize = 40ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull;

    // this works, overcommits memory while /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory is 0    
{
        void* pointer = mmap(0, fitsInMemSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);
        if(pointer == MAP_FAILED){
            perror("mmap 1");
        }else{
            std::memset(pointer, 1, fitsInMemSize);
            void* newptr = mremap(pointer, fitsInMemSize, exceedsMemSize, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
            if(newptr == MAP_FAILED){
                perror("remap 1");
                munmap(pointer, fitsInMemSize);
            }else{
                pointer = newptr;
                std::cerr << "ok 1\n";
                munmap(pointer, exceedsMemSize);
            }
        }
    }

   
    //this fails
    {
        void* pointer = mmap(0, fitsInMemSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if(pointer == MAP_FAILED){
            perror("mmap 2");
        }else{
            std::memset(pointer, 1, fitsInMemSize);
            void* newptr = mremap(pointer, fitsInMemSize, exceedsMemSize, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
            if(newptr == MAP_FAILED){
                perror("remap 2");
                munmap(pointer, fitsInMemSize);
            }else{
                pointer = newptr;
                std::cerr << "ok 2\n";
                munmap(pointer, exceedsMemSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```